# How can I add two different marker in Google Map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary, marker

I want to add two differente marker with different icon in Google map 
 but when I choose one the second marker icon is replaced per the first icon .
example : When I click on point a mark should be added to the map and when I click on Restau another marker should be added to the map with different marker , but i got markers with the same icon
Any solutions please ?

```
          map.addListener('click', function (e) {

            $(".point").on("click", function () {
                pointClicked = true;
                restauClicked = false;
            });
            $(".restau").on("click", function () {
                restauClicked = true;
                pointClicked = false;
            })
            var icons = {
                iconLocalise: {
                    url: "assets/img/localise.png", // url
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                },
                iconRestau: {
                    url: "assets/img/map-icone.png", // url
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                }
            };
            $("#savePoint").on("click", function () {
                if (pointClicked == true) {

                    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map, icons.iconLocalise)

                }
                if (restauClicked == true) {

                    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map, icons.iconRestau)

                }

            });
        });



    }
    function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map, icon) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: icon
        });
        icon = null;
        marker = null;
        alert(JSON.stringify(icon));

        map.panTo(latLng);

    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (preferably a StackOverflow code snippet) that demonstrates your issue (a clearer explanation of the problem would be helpful as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *if-else statement* that checks the value of the elements you clicked to determine the icon that you will use in the map. You can refer to the [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/z3w0s5xr/) I created that uses different marker every time I change the status of the switch from 'Default' to 'Restau'.

Here is a snippet of the if else statement I used in a code.

```
 var iconLook;
    //setting condition that check for the value of the Switch to determine the icon
    if (switchStatus.checked) {
        iconLook = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png";
    } else {
        iconLook = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png";
    }
//passing the value of the icon in the new marker that is being created
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: iconLook,
        map: map
    });
```